# What is the purpose of flex-start and flex-end on justify-items and justify-self?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

From what I know, the [`justify-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items) and [`justify-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self) CSS properties are used in CSS Grid layouts, and *don't* have any effect in Flexbox layouts (*unlike* the similarly-named but different [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) property). Indeed, MDN says in the docs for both `justify-items` and `justify-self` that

> In flexbox layouts, this property is ignored

and has a whole section with the heading **There is no justify-self in Flexbox** on the [Box Alignment in Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Alignment/Box_Alignment_in_Flexbox) page.

And yet, mysteriously, the [`justify-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items) docs list these two possible values:

> ```
> justify-items: flex-start; /* Pack flex items from the start */
> justify-items: flex-end;   /* Pack flex items from the end */
> ```

These values also show up as autocomplete suggestions in the developer tools of browsers like Chrome and Firefox if you start setting a `justify-items` or `justify-self` property.

Why do these values exist if `justify-items` and `justify-self` are ignored in Flexbox layouts? Are they specced? What do they do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an error. The `justify-items` and `justify-self` properties do not apply in flexbox.

Consider your source of information: [**MDN Web Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) (formerly Mozilla Developer Network). This resource, although normally useful and reliable, nonetheless represents *second hand information*.

The CSS definitions on MDN pages are based on official W3C documentation. MDN contributors (people) read, filter and interpret W3C data for presentation on MDN. As a result, MDN info is subject to human error. That's the problem here.

If you go directly to the spec, you'll find the correct information:

> [**7.1. Inline/Main-Axis Alignment: the `justify-items`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#justify-items-property)
>
> This property specifies the default `justify-self` for all of the
>   child boxes (including anonymous boxes) participating in this box’s
>   formatting context.

Okay. So let's go to `justify-self`.

> [**6.1. Inline/Main-Axis Alignment: the `justify-self`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#justify-self-property)
>
> *Applies to:* block-level boxes, absolutely-positioned boxes, and grid items

As noted, `justify-items` and `justify-self` do not apply to flex items.

Also note that `justify-items` and `justify-self` are applicable to multiple box models, not just CSS Grid. For more details see the [CSS Box Alignment Module specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/).

Comment: That's confusing as hell because even [Chrome suggests `flex-start`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZeUC.png) for `justify-self` -- and they had to implement the spec.

Comment: Yup, looks like an unsettled issue. Just use `auto` margins instead. @mpen

Answer (score 0):

The spec *does* actually dictate that these are valid `justify-items` and `justify-self` values. It lists the legal values of [`justify-items`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#justify-items-property) as:

> normal | stretch | [<baseline-position>](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#typedef-baseline-position) | [<overflow-position>](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#typedef-overflow-position)? [ [<self-position>](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#typedef-self-position) | left | right ] | legacy | legacy && [ left | right | center ]

and defines [`<self-position>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#typedef-self-position) as:

> ```
> <self-position> = center | start | end | self-start | self-end |
>        flex-start | flex-end
> ```

I'm not sure, but I speculate that these possible values got yanked in as possible values for `justify-self` and `justify-items` without much consideration simply by virtue of being part of the `<self-position>` category in the spec.

Regardless, the `flex-start` spec says:

> #### flex-start
>
> Only used in flex layout. [[CSS-FLEXBOX-1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#biblio-css-flexbox-1) Aligns the [alignment subject](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#alignment-subject) to be flush with the edge of the [alignment container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#alignment-container) corresponding to the [flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container)’s main-start or cross-start side, as appropriate.
>
> When used outside of a [flex formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-formatting-context), this value behaves as [start](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#valdef-self-position-start). That is, on boxes that are not [flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) (or pretending to be flex items, such as when determining the static position of an absolutely-positioned box that is a child of a [flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container)), this value behaves as start when used in the [self-alignment](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#self-alignment-properties) properties, and on boxes that are not flex containers, this value behaves as start when used in the [content-distribution properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#content-distribution-properties).

(There's analogous wording for `flex-end`.)

If we're talking about the `justify-items` or `justify-self` properties, then, if they're not being ignored, we are guaranteed to *not* be in a flex formatting context, and thus it will *always* be the case that:

> this value behaves as start.

We can see this in action in a simple Grid layout:

```css
#grid {
    display: grid;
}
#item1 {
  justify-self: flex-start;
}
#item2 {
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div id="item1">flex-start</div>
    <div id="item2">flex-end</div>
</div>
```

Of course, there's no good reason to use these over the less-confusing `start` and `end` values, so don't. But that's what they do, and why browsers support them.

MDN's documentation of what the values mean, on the other hand, is, at the time of writing, rather confusing and self-contradictory. I'll fix it in a moment, and hopefully by the time that you read this, it'll be clearer.