# Why do I see conflicting information about flexbox in docs?

Tags: css, flexbox

I was searching if space-evenly could be used in justify-content or not. As shown on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-properties)  this can be used. But according to some SO answers MDN is not correct everytime [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474480/what-is-the-purpose-of-flex-start-and-flex-end-on-justify-items-and-justify-self) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106717/why-doesnt-justify-content-stretch-work/52106730) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074275/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-baseline-value-with-justify-content-justify). So I tried reading the [W3C candidate recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property) and [Editor's draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property) about CSS flexbox-1 and both doesn't state space-evenly as a possible value in flexbox.  But on the other hand [W3C editor CSS-align-3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#propdef-justify-content) draft and [W3C working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#align-justify-content) had some conflicting information, it states that justify-content  has [content-distribution](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#typedef-content-distribution) as a valid value which applies to flex-containers which also contains space-evenly inside it. I tested it on my own and found it works on chrome and firefox but not on internet explorer. Can someone tell me which document should I trust for accurate information.

Comment: it's not conflicting. You simply need to understand the logic of CSS levels. I would call it *evolving* since things change and some ressources may become innacurate (or not 100% up to date). Check the duplicate to get more details. The reliable source is the Specification + you need to check for browser support

Comment: On MDN you see a table with the browsers that support this functionality. There you can see it is not supported by IE but all other browsers do (depending on the version)

Comment: @Temani Afif  Thanks for clearing my confusion about the specs. I went through the links and understood what you were saying but I still have one more question- In one of your answers you state that the Draft can't be given as a source and is subject to change and in not endorsed by W3C and shouldn't be cited. Then how can we know if the features we implemented in our page will be robust in future or not.

Comment: well, you know this by experience because not all the drafts are the same. There is new draft where things are still not clear and under discussion and no browser is implementing anything (example of a draft: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-3/#masonry-layout only Firefox is implementing a portion of it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66457526/8620333) and drafts that are old enough and you know that browsers have already started the implementation and it's around for a while to consider it as robust but still need to pay attention.

Comment: ^ in addtion to this, always consider the browser support. A good link is the following http://caniuse.com/ . it gives you a good state of the feature you want to implement. If there is a lot of green they you are safe. If there is plenty of red then pay attention